# Hide drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created drop-down menu such that when a user click list-menu a drop-down will appear. What I want to do is hide the drop-down when user click anywhere else. Thank for your times.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>

    <li id="woman-li"><a href="#"> <span>Woman</span> </a> </li>
    <li id="man-li"><a href="#"> <span>Man</span> </a> </li>
    <li id="health-li"><a href="#"> <span>Health</span> </a> </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="drop-down">
   <div id='woman'> 
     <h1>Woman</h1>
   </div>

  <div id='man'> 
   <h1>Man</h1>
 </div> 

 <div id='health'> 
   <h1>Health</h1>
 </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 }

.drop-down{
 border-top: none!important;
 border: 1px solid rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.98);
 margin-bottom: 2.618em; 
 }
 .drop-down #woman, .drop-down #man, .drop-down #health, .drop-down    #device,.drop-down #living{
 display: none;
 }
```

**JS**

```
var hideall = $('#woman,#man,#health');

$('#woman-li').click(function () {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#woman').show();
});

$( "#man-li" ).click(function() {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#man').show(); 
});

$( "#health-li" ).click(function() {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#health').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your JS code:

```
$("ul>li").focusout(function(){
    $(".drop-down > *").hide();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3teo4L12/)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the click event to the document body as follows:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $( hideall ).hide();
});
```

And prevent click propagation to it when one of the menu items is clicked:

```
$('#woman-li').click(function (event) {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#woman').show();
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$( "#man-li" ).click(function(event) {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#man').show(); 
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$( "#health-li" ).click(function(event) {
 $( hideall ).hide(),$('#health').show();
 event.stopPropagation();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.drop-down div').hide();
```

will hide all your dropdown divs
Then you show the one that you want

Like this:

```
var hideall = $('#woman,#man,#health');

$('#woman-li').on("click",function () {
 $('.drop-down div').hide();
    $('#woman').show();
});

$( "#man-li" ).click(function() {
 $('.drop-down div').hide();
    $('#man').show(); 
});

$( "#health-li" ).click(function() {
 $('.drop-down div').hide();
    $('#health').show();
});
```